# Chess Stack Exchange web page not loading correctly

Tags: bug

Whenever I go to the Chess Stack Exchange web page, it looks like this:

[image: #1]

[image: #2]

[image: #3]
I've done my time on stack overflow, and if I had to guess, I'd say the CSS is not loading correctly, but I don't know why.

Comment: Yeah, that's a lack of CSS. There's nothing wrong with the site, it must be something on your end. Try emptying your cache. Perhaps your browser tools will tell you why it doesn't load? How do other sites on the stackexchange.com domain look like?

Comment: @Glorfindel No just chess, I restarted and its seems OK, but the thing is that this is not the first time this has happened, it randomly loads like this and I have to restart my computer, but I suppose its just a inconvenience